# @LoadBalanced load balancer does not resolve service name in nacos

Tags: java, maven, microservices, ribbon, nacos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuPep.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJSFx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSS2X.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxsDb.png)

Registering basic_module successfully in the NACOS service registry, and also added @ LoadBalanced load balancing annotation in RestTemplateConfiguration, but still unable to parse basic_module, I use

```
restTemplate.getForObject（"http://basic_module/user/getusername",String.class);
```

The request result resttemplate was resolved to `basic_module:80`,Ultimately, it leads to `basic_module:nodename nor servname provided, or not known`。
Why is it that even if I add a load balancer and register successfully in the service registry, I cannot recognize basic_module

Comment: Do not use images for text information in Stackoverlow.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), and then edit your question.